# dateadd seconds < dateadd days issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dateadd

I have an issue where I'm trying to show the escalations for a specific time frame of a single day I.E. I want to see all the escalations for today based on the priority of the escalation.

```
SELECT tas.TASK_ID as TICKET, 
tas.TASKNAME,
chg.ASLOGID as ASSIGNEE,
DATEADD(SECOND, logs.SUBMIT_DATE , '19700101') as SUBMIT_DATE,
tas.PRIORITY,
FROM dbo.TASK as tas,
dbo.CHANGE as chg,
dbo.WORKLOG as logs
WHERE chg.ASLOGID in ('Some Users')
and tas.TASKNAME like ('Escalation%')
and chg.CHANGE_ID = tas.TASK_ID
and logs.CHANGE_ID = chg.CHANGE_ID
and logs.SUBMIT_DATE = 
    (Select MAX(logs2.SUBMIT_DATE) from dbo.WORKLOG as 
    logs2 where logs2.CHANGE_ID = logs.CHANGE_ID)
    and DATEADD(SECOND, logs.SUBMIT_DATE , '19700101') < DATEADD(DD, CASE WHEN 
    tas.PRIORITY = 0 THEN -1
    WHEN tas.PRIORITY = 1 THEN -2
    WHEN tas.PRIORITY = 2 THEN -4
    ELSE -6 END, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
Order by SUBMIT_DATE
```

The query I have seems to work in the main but I'm not sure the Second Max Select is working correctly. What happens is I can see a number of escalations at the start of the day but once they've been cleared later in the day another pops up on screen E.G. at 16:30ish yesterday the following Escalation appeared on screen. As far as I can see there's been no change to the PRIORITY.

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|     TICKET      |  TASKNAME   | ASSIGNEE |     SUBMIT_DATE     | PRIORITY |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| INC000012345678 | Escalation  | User1    | 11/06/2018 09:41:51 |        1 |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

As I've said I'm trying all the escaltions that are likely to pop for the current day and I appreciate the issue is likely with dateadd seconds then trying to count back dateadd days but I would have expected the above to have popped after 09:41? I'm relatively new to this so i might be being a little naive in how this is working.

Appreciate the adivce in getting this right and thanks in advance.

Comment: Think I may have resolved this with CAST as DATE

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by:

```
and CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, logs.SUBMIT_DATE , '19700101') as DATE) < DATEADD(DD, CASE WHEN 
tas.PRIORITY = 0 THEN -1
WHEN tas.PRIORITY = 1 THEN -2
WHEN tas.PRIORITY = 2 THEN -4
ELSE -6 END, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```